# ngAnimate parent vs child in AngularJS 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

In AngularJS 1.2, if I use a parent animation, the child animation doesn't work.

If I comment out `app.animation('.parent', function () { .. }`, then the child animation starts correctly.

How to get both parent and child animations working at the same time?

[Plunker of my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/xfkdATzHhb5uwmXvLf5y?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="anim.toggleParent()">reveal parent</button>
<button ng-click="anim.toggleChild()">reveal child</button>
<div class="parent" ng-if="!anim.showParent">
    <div class="child" ng-if="!anim.showChild">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.animation('.parent', function () {
    return {
    // ...
    };
});

// this doesn't work with parent animation =(

app.animation('.child', function () {
    return {
    // ...
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just insert `ng-animate-children` to the parent (Angular 1.2+).

```
<button ng-click="anim.toggleParent()">reveal parent</button>
<button ng-click="anim.toggleChild()">reveal child</button>
<div class="parent" ng-if="!anim.showParent" ng-animate-children>
    <div class="child" ng-if="!anim.showChild">
    </div>
</div>
```

Check the [`ngAnimate`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/api/ngAnimate) documentation:

> Keep in mind that, by default, if an animation is running, any child elements cannot be animated until the parent element's animation has completed. This blocking feature can be overridden by placing the `ng-animate-children` attribute on a parent container tag.
>       `<div class="slide-animation" ng-if="on" ng-animate-children>
>         <div class="fade-animation" ng-if="on">
>           <div class="explode-animation" ng-if="on">
>              ...
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>`
> When the `on` expression value changes and an animation is triggered then each of the elements within will all animate without the block being applied to child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this thread is closed. If so recommendation would be very helpful.

Facing the same issue here.

Angular animate has the below lines indicating that the child animations will not be triggered if parent has animation.

Not sure whether this is an issue or works as expected.

```
    //skip the animation if animations are disabled, a parent is already being animated,
    //the element is not currently attached to the document body or then completely close
    //the animation if any matching animations are not found at all.
    //NOTE: IE8 + IE9 should close properly (run closeAnimation()) in case a NO animation is not found.
    if (animationsDisabled(element, parentElement) || matches.length === 0) {
      domOperation();
      closeAnimation();
      return;
    }
```

Have raised a thread in [Angular google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/oyRyggqDSgc) referenced the issue back here.

Answer (score 0):

Also not sure if this thread is closed, but you could always edit the angular-animate.js file.  Function animationsDisabled is where angular looks for the parent element to see if it will allow the child to animate. At the top of this function I added a check to see if the parent element has a class of animation-override (can be whatever you define). This way you can override the default functionality when needed.

```
function animationsDisabled(element, parentElement) {
    if (parentElement[0].classList.contains('animation-override')) return false;

    if (rootAnimateState.disabled) return true;

    if(isMatchingElement(element, $rootElement)) {
      return rootAnimateState.disabled || rootAnimateState.running;
    }

    do {
      //the element did not reach the root element which means that it
      //is not apart of the DOM. Therefore there is no reason to do
      //any animations on it
      if(parentElement.length === 0) break;

      var isRoot = isMatchingElement(parentElement, $rootElement);
      var state = isRoot ? rootAnimateState : parentElement.data(NG_ANIMATE_STATE);
      var result = state && (!!state.disabled || !!state.running);

      if(isRoot || result) {
        return result;
      }

      if(isRoot) return true;
    }
    while(parentElement = parentElement.parent());

    return true;
  }
}]);
```